Use inheritance in definitions for json column
I have a column definition that works ok for persisting and querying typed json data
Entities
public class TimeLineDefinition()
{
    public DateTime StartDateUtc { get; init; }
}

public class ProductData()
{
    public ProductData(TimeLineDefinition timeLineDefinition)
    {
        
        TimeLineDefinition = timeLineDefinition;
    }
    
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public TimeLineDefinition TimeLineDefinition {get;set;}
}

Mapping
public class ProductDataConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<ProductData>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ProductData> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        
        builder.Property(p => p.StartDateTimeUtc)
            .HasColumnType("timestamp with time zone");

        builder.OwnsOne(  t => t.TimeLineDefinition ,navigationBuilder => {
            navigationBuilder.ToJson();
        });
            
    }
}

This Setup persists the object TimeLineDefinition as json in the column TimeLineDefinition .
I now want to have a type
public class TimeLineDefinitionWithEndDate() :TimeLineDefinition
{
    
        public DateTime EndDateUtc { get; init; }
}

that should persist and read  StartDateUtc and EndDateUtc.  Is  this possible with PostgresProvider in EF?

Don't think so. It means that Discriminator should be stored in JSON. Also it means that LINQ translator should be improved for such cases.
